# How to emit SocketIO event on the serverside

Tags: python, django, websocket, socket.io, gevent-socketio

I'm running a gevent-socketio Django application.

I have something similar to this class

```
@namespace('/connect')
class ConnectNamespace(BaseNamespace):

    def on_send(self, data):
        # ...
```

However, if I receive the events from the javascript client, everything works and for instance `send` event is processed correctly

I'm a little bit lost if I want to `emit` some event on the server side. I can do it inside the class with `socket.send_packet`

But now I want to link some event to `post_save` signal, so I'd like to `send_packet` from outside this namespace class, one way of doing this would be

```
ConnectNamespaceInstance.on_third_event('someeventname')
```

I just can't figure out how can I get the instance of ConnectNamespaceInstance

To sum it up, I just want to send an event to javascript client after I receive `post_save` signal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504320/socket-io-namespaces-channels-co

Comment: i got the same issue,and cannot solved... Any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think suggested duplicate answers my question

Comment: do you want to communicate with a dedicated client or broadcast events?

Comment: once I have the instance of the class, I could do both I guess, I'd just need to use `BroadcastMixin`'s methods to send it to everybody

Comment: what is the context of where the signal handler is executed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you probably want to do is add a module variable to track connections, say `_connections`, like so:

```
_connections = {}

@namespace('/connect')
class ConnectNamespace(BaseNamespace):
```

and then add `initialize` and `disconnect` methods that use some happy identifier you can reference later:

```
def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
    _connections[id(self)] = self
    super(ConnectNamespace, self).initialize(*args, **kwargs)

def disconnect(self, *args, **kwargs):
    del _connections[id(self)]
    super(ConnectNamespace, self).disconnect(*args, **kwargs)
```

When you need to generate an event, you can then just look up the right connection in the `_connections` variable, and fire off the event with `emit`.

(Didn't test any of this, but I've used a similar pattern in many other languages: don't see any reason why this wouldn't work in Python as well).

Comment: I was wondering whether there is some build-in tool for doing this in the framework, but this is a really nice workaround I should have thought of! +1 :) thank you

Comment: any example for broadcasting to channel with this solution?

Comment: This helped me to send messages on post_save signal in Django. Really nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Other then Femi's answer, which I think certainly works. Using Redis would probably give you a bit more flexibility and using greenlet from gevent may qualify this approach as a bit more "in the framework", since you are already using gevent-socketio :D

```
REDIS_HOST = getattr(settings, 'REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1')


class YourNamespace(BaseNamespace):

    def _listener(self, channel_label_you_later_call_in_post_save):
        pubsub = redis.StrictRedis(REDIS_HOST).pubsub()
        pubsub.subscribe(chan)
        while True:
            for i in pubsub.listen():
                self.send({'message_data': i}, json=True) 

    def recv_message(self, message):
        if is_message_to_subscribe(message):
            self.spawn(self.listener, get_your_channel_label(message))
```

And in your post_save, you can do

```
red = redis.StrictRedis(REDIS_HOST)
red.publish(channel_label, message_data)
```