# io.on('connection',...) vs io.sockets.on('connection',...)

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, mean-stack

I am using [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io) and the [Mean](http://mean.io/) stack for a web app. I started the server for socket on 3006 port..

```
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
http.listen(3006);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
```

Both of these seem to work on connection.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Socket succesfully connected with id: '+socket.id);
});
```

and...

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log('Socket succesfully connected with id: '+socket.id);
});
```

What is the difference between `io.on` and `io.sockets.on` and which one should I use on first time connection..?

Though [socket.on npm page](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io)  uses `io.on` why is it working for `io.sockets.on`

Comment: Not 100%, but I think it's just an alias. As with `io.sockets.emit` and `io.emit` seen [here](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit).

Comment: @Ben Fortune well when i have both of them at the same time, both of them are executed..is it wrong to use io.on('connection',...) twice..?

Answer (score 18):

The default namespace that Socket.IO clients connect to by default is: `/`. 
It is identified by `io.sockets` or simply `io` ([docs](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#)).

This example copied from the documentation:

```
// the following two will emit to all the sockets connected to `/`

io.sockets.emit('hi', 'everyone');

io.emit('hi', 'everyone');           // short form
```

I assume it is the same for 'on', as it is for 'emit': using 'io.sockets' is equivalent to using 'io' only, it's just a shorter form.

To “namespace” your sockets, means assigning different endpoints or paths (which can be useful).

From an answer to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504320/socket-io-namespaces-channels-co):

"Socket.io does all the work for you as if it is two separate instances, but still limits the information to one connection, which is pretty smart."